# Sequences that tend to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If the limit of one sequence $\{a_n\}$ is zero and the limit of another sequence $\{b_n\}$ is also zero does that mean that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n/b_n) = 1$?

Comment: What have you tried? What happens when $a_n=b_n^2$? What happens when $b_n=2a_n$?

Comment: Sequence $\frac{1}{n} $ and $\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: We can conclude essentially *nothing* about the behaviour of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

Comment: So for shorthand we say: $0/0$ is an **indeterminate form**.

Answer (score 9):

Given $b_n$ whose limit is 0, we can choose $a_n$ to make the limit:

- 1: set $a_n = b_n$
- 0: set $a_n = b_n^2$, or even $a_n = 0$
- Some other constant c: set $a_n = cb_n$
- Undefined: $a_n = (-1)^nb_n$
- Infinite: $a_n = \sqrt{|b_n|}$

So we can make it basically anything.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $a_n = \dfrac 1 n$ and $b_n = \dfrac 1 {n^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not.

- $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$,
- $b_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$,
- Hence, $r_n=\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=(-1)^n$ and the limit of $r_n$ does not even exist.

Answer (score 2):

If we want an example such that the limit exists: Let $r \in \Bbb{R}$ be your favorite number, suppose that $b_n \to 0$, and let $a_n = r b_n$. Then $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n/b_n \to r$.

If we want an example such that the limit does not exist: Let $b_n \to 0$ and $\{c_n\}$ be your favorite *bounded* sequence such that $\lim c_n$ does not exist. Let $a_n = c_n b_n$, then $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n/b_n = c_n$, and the limit does not exist.

But, don't consider this a disappointing result! We would be in a much different world if this was not the case; for example, imagine how boring L'Hopital's rule would be.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=1/n$, $b_n=1/n^2$. What can  you say on the ratio?