# Larger and larger sequences that tend to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

While answering [Sequences that tend to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848415/sequences-that-tend-to-zero/), I came across the following related question:

Suppose we have a sequence $b_n$ whose limit is 0 as n tends to infinity.

Then can we always find another sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n$ also has 0 as the limit, but $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n} = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Here's a simple example. Define a sequence $a_n$ such that 
$$a_n=\sqrt{|b_n|}$$. In that case, $a_n$ tends to $0$ and $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ also tends to $0$.

Comment: You have to watch out for $b_n=0$, but that is easy to fix.

Comment: Oh, I guess I was thinking in terms of series which is why this did not work. This is a correct answer for this question as I asked, but I wanted to ask something else. I will upvote this and change the question.

Comment: Actually it is better to ask that separately I guess, I will accept this answer for here.